# Interface relation with abstract class C#

Tags: c#

I read that Interface is implicitly pure abstract. So why the methods of the class that implements interface does not prefix with override keyword?

```
interface IA
{
    void Method();
}

class B : IA
{
   public void Method()       // why it is not "public override void Method()"
   {
       Console.Writeline("A derived");
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
For those who want to know where i read it. Go to abstract classes v/s interface section of below page:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6118/All-about-abstract-classes

Comment: Because interface does not provide an implementation. The `B` class does not override, but implements a method.

Comment: @zerkms : make an answer of your comment, as that's exactly what it is :)

Comment: So how interface become implicitly pure abstract class?

Comment: @GauravSharma where did you read it actually?

Comment: As far as I know C# took a lot of concepts from C++. In C++, there are no interfaces, only classes that may have functions that are "pure virtual", i.e. abstract. A class that has one or more pure virtual methods cannot be instantiated (i.e. it is abstract). A class that has all methods which are pure virtual is equivalent to a C# interface. So, yes, OP's reasoning is correct. An interface is really an abstract class where none of the methods have an implementation, and in C# it gets some special treatment (e.g. limited multiple inheritance for polymorphism).

Comment: @zerkms http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6118/All-about-abstract-classes        go to Abstract class vs. Interface section

Comment: @Gaurav Sharma: I'd say that that guy doesn't use the terms properly.

Comment: @Gigi : C# took its basic syntax from C, but so did a great number of modern languages (C++, Java, javaScript and a lot more). That does not mean that its main concepts come from there. C#'s main concepts are much closer to Java's. Thinking in terms of C++ concepts when working with C# is a failproof recipe for failure (pun intended).

Comment: @Falanwe I disagree. I'm not saying you should think in C++ terms when using OOP in C#. I'm merely saying that knowing a bit of history helps put things into perspective. C++ predates both Java and C# by quite a bit, and their implementations can be seen as adaptations of C++ OOP, with many added restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface is not a pure abstract class, it's just an interface.

An interface declares a contract with public methods and properties that anything that implements it must respect. It does not provide anything except signatures.

On the other hand, an abstract class provides a base implementation for some or all of its features. It can provide actual logic. Interfaces cannot.

Overriding is replacing the logic in a method by another logic. As interfaces never provide any logic (they can't), it would be pointless to use the keyword `override`.

Two other very important differences:

- You can only derive from one class (abstract or not), but you can implement as many interfaces as you want.
- You can have structs implementing interfaces, but you cannot make an abstract struct, as struct can't inherit from one another.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to think of interfaces is to consider them with a *can* relationship to the class you mark them against, as opposed to a parent class which can be thought as a *is a* relationship.

In your example there is no need to mention the override keyword, as you are not overriding any implemented behaviour, you are simple saying that you class needs to fulfil its contract to supply a Method() implementation.

Although interfaces can be thought of like a purely abstract class, there is a distinct difference in that a class can be marked to implement several interfaces whereas it can only inherit from *one* parent class.

```
class B : IA, IB, IC
```

So, you can pass your instance of your class as any of these interface types depending on which contact you need to to expose to a method